# Como pegar todos os cookies usando CookieManager no Android e de forma mais eficiente?

Tags: java, android

Estou fazendo uma biblioteca *cross-platform*, e um dos recursos é de obter os cookies do WebView. Mas, existe uma "inconsistencia" entre as APIs do Android e do iOS.

No iOS existe o método:

```
[[[wkconfig websiteDataStore] httpCookieStore] getAllCookies: ^(NSArray<NSHTTPCookie *> * array) {
// ....
}
```

Isso permite obter todos os cookies do WebView, e queria reproduzir o mesmo no Android. Mas, no Android, o único método existente é:

```
public abstract String getCookie (String url)
```

Isso requer que eu ofereça um `url` para os cookies que quero obter. Para piorar, ele retorna uma String, da seguinte forma: `key=value` e pode existir mais de um cookie, delimitado por `;`. Isso é completamente ineficiente.

Então minha pergunta é:

- **Como posso obter a lista de todos os cookies (não de um site especifico) usando o CookieManager?**

Comment: No Android vai ser difícil. Suponho que terá que recorrer a gambiarras como buscar todos os sites navegados no histórico e pegar individualmente os seus cookies ou então criar um processo que intercepte a criação e leitura de cookies e os catalogar.

Comment: @AugustoVasques antes eu tinha pensado em ler o `mCookiesList` (algo assim) que é um valor privado lá da classe do CookieManager, so que.... pelo que vi, no Android 5 isso foi alterado e passou a ser alguma função nativa. Eu não tinha pensando em ver o historico, vou ver sobre isso. Só passo raiva com Android, as APIs são ******. E pior, não tem como deletar somente um único cookie ou saber o tempo de expiração (ou as propriedades, como HTTPOnly, Secure....). Padrão Android.